# Why does my discrete fourier transform of two sin waves have a huge spike at zero?

Tags: go, signal-processing, fft

I'm able to take the fourier transform of the addition of two sin waves (say of frequency 1 and 10). I convert that into a frequency-magnintude plot by using the sampling frequency calculated from the duration and number of samples.

I get two distinct blips at 1 and 10, as expected, but also this huge spike at 0 that I can't explain.

Code that generates adds the sin waves together to create the signal:

```
const INPUT_NUM_SAMPLES = 1 << 10
const INPUT_DURATION = 10
INPUT_FREQS := []float64{1, 10}

fftInput := make([]complex128, INPUT_NUM_SAMPLES)
for _, freq := range INPUT_FREQS {
    for i := range fftInput {
        inputPoint := float64(i) / float64(INPUT_NUM_SAMPLES) * INPUT_DURATION
        fftInput[i] += complex(inputPoint, math.Cos(inputPoint*freq*math.Pi*2))
    }
}
```

Code that performs the fourier transform:

```
fftOutput := fourier.NewCmplxFFT(INPUT_NUM_SAMPLES).Coefficients(make([]complex128, len(fftInput)), fftInput)
```

Code that generates the frequency-magnitude plot

```
R := float64(INPUT_NUM_SAMPLES) / float64(INPUT_DURATION)
fmt.Printf("Sampling frequency: %f\n", R)
freqMag := make([]complex128, len(fftOutput))
for index, value := range fftOutput {
    freqMag[index] = complex((float64(index)/INPUT_NUM_SAMPLES)*R, math.Sqrt(real(value)*real(value)+imag(value)*imag(value)))
}
```

Plot of frequency-magnitude (omitting the other symmetric half):
[image]
Plot of signal:
[image]

I've tried a few things, including:

1. Using a different fft library
2. Inverting the real and imaginary components of the input, which oddly seemed to make zero difference.
   I expected two blips at 1 and 10, and that would be it (not counting the symmetry, the other side of the output has been omitted from the the plot)

Comment: My FFT is a little rusty, but could it be that floating point values have finite granularity and [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) using FP values near zero can produce a noticeable error in the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right-hand side of the line

```
fftInput[i] += complex(inputPoint, math.Cos(inputPoint*freq*math.Pi*2))
```

constructs a complex value with real part `inputPoint` and imaginary part `math.Cos(inputPoint*freq*math.Pi*2)`, like

```
x(t) = 2 t + j (cos(t π 2) + cos(t π 4)),  0 ≤ t < 10.
```

So the input signal is a ramp (due to the real part) plus a sum of two sinusoids (from the imaginary part). The ramp is nonnegative, which explains the large spike in the spectrum at frequency 0 (DC). Furthermore, the ramp is discontinuous at the interval endpoints, explaining the other significant low frequency components.

Based on your description, I believe what you intended is that the input signal be two real-valued sinusoids. Change the line to:

```
fftInput[i] += complex(math.Cos(inputPoint*freq*math.Pi*2), 0.0)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Guess I was a bit naive about how the input was supposed to work. I assumed the real represented the "time" of the sample and the imaginary the "magnitude".

Comment: @MichaelHermenault, please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark at top left of this answer. Thanks :)